# Export an image in GEE to open it in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I used following codes to export image from the GEE to open in ArcGIS Pro:

```js
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-114.3461, 51.2335, -113.8015, 50.8140]);
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}


var S2_collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED").filterDate('2019-08-01', '2019-08-30').filterBounds(geometry)
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20)).map(maskS2clouds);


var S2_bands = ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'];
var S2_mosaic = S2_collection.median().select(S2_bands).clip(geometry);
var S2_display = {bands: S2_bands, min: 0, max: 0.3};
Map.addLayer(S2_mosaic, S2_display, "S2_Image");
Map.centerObject(geometry);


var projection = S2_mosaic.projection();
print(projection)

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: S2_mosaic,
  description: 'imageToDriveExample_transform',
  crs: projection.crs,
  crsTransform: projection.transform,
  region: geometry
});
```

However, no error in console but in tasts. When I push the Run button it said:  Invalid "argument, crs transform was not a string or array"

Answer (score 0):

When using the "Export" command, if these "crs" and "crsTransform" inputs are not given, the values associated with the image will be selected by default. But if you want the image to be output in another projection, you can use "Reproject" before exporting:

```
S2_mosaic = S2_mosaic.reproject({
   crs: another_projection.crs(),
   crsTransform: another_projection.transform().getInfo()['transform']
 })

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: S2_mosaic,
  description: 'imageToDriveExample_transform',
  region: geometry
});
```