# How to access image CRS transform from ee.Projection object in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, image

I used the following script to export an image from Earth Engine. I am trying to specify the `crs_transform` parameter argument in the `Export.image.toDrive` function using the "transform" property of the image's `ee.Projection` object. I can see that when I print the image's projection object that there is a field for "transform" containing a valid array element, but the export function throw's an error:

> Invalid "argument, crs transform was not a string or array"

How can I retrieve the image's CRS transform?

```js
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-114.3, 51.2, -113.8, 50.8]);
  
var S2_collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED")
  .filterDate('2019-08-01', '2019-08-30')
  .filterBounds(geometry) 
  // ...map a cloud masking function
    
var S2_mosaic = S2_collection.median()
    
var projection = S2_mosaic.projection();
print(projection)
    
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: S2_mosaic,
  description: 'imageToDriveExample_transform',
  crs: projection.crs,
  crsTransform: projection.transform,  // <-- here's the problem
  region: geometry
});
```

Comment: Please post only one Question per question.  [Export an image in GEE to open it in ArcGIS Pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/443078/export-an-image-in-gee-to-open-it-in-arcgis-pro)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `projection.transform` as if the `projection` variable is a JavaScript literal object, but it is an Earth Engine server-side `ee.Projection` object whose properties cannot be accessed by dot or bracket notation. You need to transfer the `ee.Projection` object client-side to work with it as a JavaScript literal object; you can use the `evaluate` function to do this:

```js
projection.evaluate(function(proj_obj) {
  Export.image.toDrive({
    image: S2_mosaic,
    description: 'imageToDriveExample_transform',
    crs: proj_obj.crs,
    crsTransform: proj_obj.transform,
    region: geometry });
});
```

Here is some information on [server vs client](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server).

Also, the default CRS transform for image collection reductions (e.g. `ee.Image.median`) is 1-degree pixel scale in WGS84 EPSG:4326 projection. My guess is that it not what you want. If you'd like your export CRS to match the CRS of some other image in the collection, you should get it from an unaltered image like `S2_collection.first().projection()`. Here is more information on the [default projection](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections#the-default-projection).

Comment: very helpful, thanks! Also very non-intuitive to me why the typical workaround to the "client-side vs. server-side" challenge-- that is, using `.getInfo()`-- doesn't work in this case. E.g., `crsTransform: projection.transform().getInfo()`

Comment: The CRS transform is a weird case where there is not an EE method to fetch it i.e. `ee.Projection.transform` is not a method like `ee.Projection.crs' or `ee.Projection.nominalScale()` are. The CRS transform can only be accessed from the client-side representation of the `ee.Projection` object.

Comment: Interesting! So even though `ee.Projection.transform()` exists, it's not doing something equivalent to `ee.Projection.crs()` or `ee.Projection.nominalScale()`?

Comment: It returns a result that is not compatible with the `crsTransform` parameter. Try `var foo = ee.Projection('EPSG:4326').transform().aside(print)` and see that it is not formatted as `[xScale, xShearing, xTranslation, yShearing, yScale, yTranslation]`