# Unexpected crsTransform after reducing an ImageCollection: nominal scale shows 111319.49079327357

Tags: python, coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, affine-transformation, geemap

I have created an Image from an Imagecollection and I want to export it and to define the crsTransform parameter. [I have read the documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-image-tocloudstorage)  and [the post on this forum](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/443080/how-to-access-image-crs-transform-from-ee-projection-object-in-earth-engine) and tried to export it , and it exported the image, but the resulted image was very weird.

The image is sentinel-2 "EPSG:4326" . I have visualize it before so I can tell that the image is fine.

This how I tried to export it, using the crsTransform parameter:

```
import geemap
import ee 

##.... getting the image and use reduce regions

#export
 task=ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage(**{
        'image':img,
        'region':fct.geometry(),#this is the feature collection I used to get the image
        'description':'my_task',
        'fileNamePrefix':'result/sentinel2/my_image,
        'scale':10,
        'crs':"EPSG:4326",
        'crsTransform':img.projection().getInfo()['transform'],##this is the crsTransform
        'bucket':"my_bucket",
        'fileFormat':'GeoTIFF',
        'skipEmptyTiles':True})
            
    task.start()
```

The task is running but the result image is very weird.

When I print image projection, I get this:

```
img.projection().getInfo()
>>>{'type': 'Projection', 'crs': 'EPSG:4326', 'transform': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]}
```

which made me suspect that the problem is with the transform, as in the example it seems to be transform affine matrix, and here I'm not sure why it has only 1 and 0.

Another thing that I found weird is that when I print the projection using nominal scale I get this value:

```
img.projection().nominalScale().getInfo()
>>>111319.49079327357
```

this value confused me.

So, I actually need help in finding the problem I have with exporting image with the crsTransform parameter.

Comment: The reason your image is in EPSG:4326 is explained here https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections#the-default-projection but you don't want to use this for your export. Instead you probably want to use a `crs` that is suitable for your region and specify both `crs` and `scale` of 10 meters in your export, OR `crs` and `crsTransform` with a transform suitable for your region. By the way, the [1,0,0,0,1,0] is the identity transform, again because by default the image result from reducing an image collection is EPSG:4326 (the transform specifies 1-degree cells).

Comment: The 111319.49079327357 meters is the size of one 1-degree cell (approximately) at the equator.

Comment: @OliverLopez shouldn't it show 10 for 10m resolution?

Comment: for an image from the original S2 collection, yes (depending on which band you select). For an image derived from an image collection where you applied a reducer or a mosaic operation, not until you specify a "pull" operation -- see also: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/scale#scale-of-analysis

Comment: @OliverLopez so, in order to get the right transform, should I get it from an image of the image collection before I apply the reducer?

Comment: Yes, that's one option: get the transform information from one of the bands/images before the reducer. Note that not all images in your image collection will necessarily have the same crs and transform. In fact, not all bands within a single S2 image have the same transform because they have different native scales.

Comment: @OliverLopez thank you for your answer! than, if I understand correct, using the crs +scale should provide mt the same results, right? then why should someone use the crsTransform?

Comment: I collected all this information along with references and some extra information into an answer -- please accept it as an answer if you think it answered your main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the image shows a nominal scale of 111319.49079327357 (meters) is because the image has the default crs `EPSG:4326` and crsTransform `[1,0,0,0,1,0]` which corresponds to a grid of 1-degree cells (approximately 111319 meters at the equator).

The reason the image has these default `crs` and `crsTransform` values is explained in the documentation ([here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections#the-default-projection)). Basically, when you perform an operation to reduce an image collection to a single image, it is ambiguous at which scale you want the computation to happen. A single image might contain bands at different native scales (such as Sentinel-2 images, in which some bands have 10m native scale, while others 20m, etc), and an image collection might contain images with different `crs` values (e.g. two images at different UTM zones).

Earth engine allows you to define an image as a result of reducing such image collection without worrying about these differences. However, when you want to export the image (whether to drive, cloud storage, as an asset, etc), then you need to resolve this ambiguity.

The documentation explains ([here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/exporting#exporting-images)) that you can specify either `crs` and `crsTransform` for full control of the output, or you can specify `crs` and `scale`. Specifying scale is a shortcut which fills in the values of `crsTransform` for you, but makes an assumption about the origin:

> As a shortcut, you can specify a scale parameter and Earth Engine will calculate a crsTransform parameter for you. However, simply setting the scale of an image does not specify the origin of the projection, and may result in an image that is shifted relative to another image with the same pixel size!

> The reason for the potential shift is that the scale parameter is used to populate the xScale and yScale values of the crsTransform, but the xTranslation and yTranslation values are calculated so that if they are divided by the corresponding xScale and yScale values the remainder will be zero. These parameters specify a pixel grid where the projection's origin is at the corner of a pixel. This convention differs from the translation parameters used by some data providers, which use grids that are offset from the projection's origin. For example, Landsat images provided by USGS use translation parameters that are offset by a 1/2 pixel from the projection's origin (15m offset for the 30m bands) while Sentinel-2 images provided by ESA use translation parameters that are aligned with the projection's origin. If the crsTransform specified in an export do not match the crsTransform of the original image, the output pixels will be resampled (using nearest neighbor by default), which will make the resulting image be shifted relative to the original image.

> To sum up, if you need to match the exported image's pixels to a specific image, make sure to use the crs and crsTransform parameters for full control of the grid.

I.e. you might want to use `crsTransform` if you want full control of the export grid, e.g. if you use Landsat images and want them to match exactly to the original Landsat images. For Sentinel-2 images, you might be fine with just using `crs` and `scale`.

You can use any `crs` that you think is suitable for your analysis/region of study, and of course you can retrieve the information (both `crs` and `crsTransform`) from one of the bands of the original images.

Comment: thank you for the answer! regard "if you use Landsat images and want them to match exactly to the original Landsat images" , did you mean landsat with sentinel?